# How do you define a toolchain in cbp2make for gfortran?

Tags: codeblocks

I'm messing around with cbp2make for the first time.  In this case, I'm compiling Fortran using gfortran on Windows.  I'm getting this message:

---

"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\cbp2make.exe" -in QBtimeparser.cbp
Starting cbp2make rev.147...
Using default configuration.
Loading file 'QBtimeparser.cbp': [DONE]
Generating makefile(s): QBtimeparser.cbp.mak: Warning: toolchain 'gfortran' for target 'Debug' is not defined.
Warning: toolchain 'gfortran' for target 'Release' is not defined.
Warning: toolchain 'gfortran' for target 'Debug' is not defined.
Warning: toolchain 'gfortran' for target 'Release' is not defined.
[DONE]

---

Seems obvious to me that cbp2make does know where gfortran is located, for the targets. (Correct me if I an wrong, please.) I would have thought that cbp2make woould pick up the location from the .cbp file.  Silly me...

Can someone post an example of using the toolchain option to allow cbp2make find that it is looking for?  My install diectory for gfortran is the standard installed place:

C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin

And please feel free to post examples of any other options to cbp2make that you find you are always having to use ( if any) to generate a proper makefile for a partiular platform. I may be porting this to Ubuntu later and trying CodeBlocks there.

Thanks. You folks are the best.

Tried to execute cbp2make as indicated in the post.